# What does a[arr1[i]]=true do?

Tags: javascript

I am a JavaScript beginner. I have previously worked in other programming languages (C, C++ etc). What is the statement `a[arr1[i]]=true;` doing?

```
function diff(arr1, arr2) {
    var newArr = [];
    // Same, same; but different.

    var a=[];
    for(var i=0;i<arr1.length;i++)
        a[arr1[i]]=true;

    for(var j=0;j<arr2.length;j++)
        if(a[arr2[j]])
            delete a[arr2[j]];
        else
            a[arr2[j]]=true;

    for(var k in a)
        newArr.push(k);

    return newArr;
}
```

Comment: There are equivalent constructs in both C and C++, which you claim to know.

Comment: @Blindy: In other C, C++, we usually provide array's index inside `[]`. Its strange to see an array as index inside another array.

Comment: They are indexes. I don't get what's confusing, you index `a` with `arr1[i]`, again identical to their equivalent C and C++ constructs.

Comment: @FahadUddin It's not an array as index. It's `arr1[i]` as index, which evaluates to a number.

Comment: @HiI'mfrogatto: It wouldn't always be a number. It could be a string sometimes..

Comment: @FahadUddin Strings are also ok.

Answer (score 1):

It seems that `a` is a list of booleans, so that particular assignment sets one of `a`'s indices to `true`. That index is computed by dereferencing `arr1`.

In a comment above you expressed a worry to the effect that an array is used as an index inside another array. But no need to worry about that, because it's not the array itself (viz. `arr1`) that's used as an index, but an element of that array (viz. `arr1[i]`, for some i).

Answer (score 1):

You're wondering about the syntax `a[arr1[i]]`. It's simple:

- `arr1[i]` value is an index for array `a`.
- If `arr1[i]` value is a number, 5 as an example. So it will be: `a[5]=true`. Nothing's special in this case.
- As you said in the comment, `arr1[i]` might be a `string`, `"boy"` for example. Then, it will be: `a["boy"]=true`.

You should know that array index in JavaScript could be a string. But be careful, as W3School said, if you use a named index, JavaScript will redefine the array to a standard object. After that, all array methods and properties will produce incorrect results. For example:

```
var person = [];
person["firstName"] = "John";
person["lastName"] = "Doe";
person["age"] = 46;
var x = person.length;         // person.length will return 0
var y = person[0];             // person[0] will return undefined
```

For more detail, take a look at the warning part in [W3School](http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_arrays.asp) about this.

Answer (score 1):

Here's your code with comments explaining what's going on and sample output

```
var arr1 = [1,2,'foo','bar'];
var arr2 = [2,3,'foo'];
var diff = diff(arr1, arr2);

console.log( diff ); // ["1", "3", "bar"]

function diff(arr1, arr2) {
    var newArr = [];
    var a=[];

    // Loop through arr1
    //  set the value of each entry as an index in array `a`
    //  set the value of the entry in `a` to true
    for(var i=0;i<arr1.length;i++)
        a[arr1[i]]=true;
    //  console.log(a); // [1: true, 2: true, foo: true, bar: true]

    // Loop through arr2
    //  check if each entry exists as an index in array `a`
    //  if it does, delete the value from array `a`
    //  if not, set the value of the entry in `a` to true
    for(var j=0;j<arr2.length;j++)
        if(a[arr2[j]])
            delete a[arr2[j]];
        else
            a[arr2[j]]=true;
    //  console.log(a); // [1: true, 3: true, bar: true]

    // put all of the indexs of array `a` to values in `newArr`
    for(var k in a)
        newArr.push(k);

    return newArr;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/daCrosby/6rcf1j72/

---

From a code-cleanup side, If you want a shorter function you could use something like one of these:

```
console.log( "Looping", diffLoop ); // [1, "bar", 3]
console.log( "Filtering", diffFilter ); // [1, "bar", 3]

function diffLoop(arr1, arr2){
    var arr = arr1;

    for(var j=0; j<arr2.length; j++)
        if( arr.indexOf( arr2[j] ) > -1 )
            arr.splice(arr.indexOf( arr2[j] ), 1);
        else
            arr.push(arr2[j]);
    return arr;
}

function diffFilter(arr1, arr2){
    var arr = arr1.concat(arr2);
    return arr.filter(function(i) {
        var in1 = arr1.indexOf(i) < 0;
        var in2 = arr2.indexOf(i) < 0;
        return (in1 || in2) && !(in1 && in2);
    });
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/daCrosby/6rcf1j72/1/

Answer (score 0):

Same logic as in high level languages applies here as well.

This can easily be clarified splitting this to small blocks.

```
a[arr1[i]]=true;
```

arr1 - An array of integer

a - An array of boolean